# React Transition Group: Can I apply classname to deeper child when using TransitionGroup/CSSTransition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

I have this setup:

Parent:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  {
    items.map((child, index) => {
      // do stuff
      return (
        <CSSTransition key={index} nodeRef={items.nodeRef} timeout={1000} classNames={'item'}>
          <ChildComponent key={index} item={item} />
        </CSSTransition>
    })
  }
</TransitionGroup
```

Child:

```
<div> // classname gets attached here
  <div> // but I want classname here instead
    { //stuff }
  </div>
</div>
```

With this, I am able to apply the enter/exit classnames to the most outer divs of ChildComponents when they enter/exit.
However, I want to apply the animation specifically to the inner layer of divs in the ChildComponent. Is there any way I can apply the CSSTransition classnames to the inner layer of divs instead?
And yes, I absolutely need the outer div for CSS formatting.

I apologize for not showing actual code. I was able to get a working version based off of the example from https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition. I have tried moving CSSTransition down a layer into the child, but that does not set the classname as desired.

Please do let me know if this is even possible or if I should look into an alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there are CSS selectors that allow you to add CSS properties to children, which solves this problem entirely.

You can do something like this:

```
.item-enter > div:first-child {
  // css stuff
}
```